# Some Addresses Work In Function And Others Don't?

Tags: erc-20, javascript, bignumber

I have the below code running based on a series of wallet addresses placed into an array for `arbAgainst`.

```
    const main = async () => {
        const { token0Contract, token1Contract, token0, token1 } = await getTokenAndContract(arbFor, arbAgainst[i])
        uPair = await getPairContract(uFactory, token0.address, token1.address)
        sPair = await getPairContract(sFactory, token0.address, token1.address)

        console.log(`uPair Address: ${uPair._address}`)
        console.log(`sPair Address: ${sPair._address}\n`)

        uPair.events.Swap({}, async () => {
            if (!isExecuting) {
                isExecuting = true

                const priceDifference = await checkPrice('Uniswap', token0, token1)
                const routerPath = await determineDirection(priceDifference)

                if (!routerPath) {
                    console.log(`No Arbitrage Currently Available\n`)
                    console.log(`-----------------------------------------\n`)
                    isExecuting = false
                    return
                }

                const isProfitable = await determineProfitability(routerPath, token0Contract, token0, token1)

                if (!isProfitable) {
                    console.log(`No Arbitrage Currently Available\n`)
                    console.log(`-----------------------------------------\n`)
                    isExecuting = false
                    return
                }

                const receipt = await executeTrade(routerPath, token0Contract, token1Contract)

                isExecuting = false
            }
        })

        sPair.events.Swap({}, async () => {
            if (!isExecuting) {
                isExecuting = true

                const priceDifference = await checkPrice('Sushiswap', token0, token1)
                const routerPath = await determineDirection(priceDifference)

                if (!routerPath) {
                    console.log(`No Arbitrage Currently Available\n`)
                    console.log(`-----------------------------------------\n`)
                    isExecuting = false
                    return
                }

                const isProfitable = await determineProfitability(routerPath, token0Contract, token0, token1)

                if (!isProfitable) {
                    console.log(`No Arbitrage Currently Available\n`)
                    console.log(`-----------------------------------------\n`)
                    isExecuting = false
                    return
                }

                const receipt = await executeTrade(routerPath, token0Contract, token1Contract)

                isExecuting = false
            }
        })

        console.log("Waiting for swap event...")
    }

    const checkPrice = async (exchange, token0, token1) => {
        isExecuting = true

        console.log(`Swap Initiated on ${exchange}, Checking Price...\n`)

        const currentBlock = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()

        const uPrice = await calculatePrice(uPair)
        const sPrice = await calculatePrice(sPair)

        const uFPrice = Number(uPrice).toFixed(units)
        const sFPrice = Number(sPrice).toFixed(units)
        const priceDifference = (((uFPrice - sFPrice) / sFPrice) * 100).toFixed(2)

        console.log(`Current Block: ${currentBlock}`)
        console.log(`-----------------------------------------`)
        console.log(`UNISWAP   | ${token1.symbol}/${token0.symbol}\t | ${uFPrice}`)
        console.log(`SUSHISWAP | ${token1.symbol}/${token0.symbol}\t | ${sFPrice}\n`)
        console.log(`Percentage Difference: ${priceDifference}%\n`)

        return priceDifference
    }

    const determineDirection = async (priceDifference) => {
        console.log(`Determining Direction...\n`)

        if (priceDifference >= difference) {

            console.log(`Potential Arbitrage Direction:\n`)
            console.log(`Buy\t -->\t Uniswap`)
            console.log(`Sell\t -->\t Sushiswap\n`)
            return [uRouter, sRouter]

        } else if (priceDifference <= -(difference)) {

            console.log(`Potential Arbitrage Direction:\n`)
            console.log(`Buy\t -->\t Sushiswap`)
            console.log(`Sell\t -->\t Uniswap\n`)
            return [sRouter, uRouter]

        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    const determineProfitability = async (_routerPath, _token0Contract, _token0, _token1) => {
        console.log(`Determining Profitability...\n`)

        // This is where you can customize your conditions on whether a profitable trade is possible.
        // This is a basic example of trading WETH/SHIB...

        let reserves, exchangeToBuy, exchangeToSell

        if (_routerPath[0]._address == uRouter._address) {
            reserves = await getReserves(sPair)
            exchangeToBuy = 'Uniswap'
            exchangeToSell = 'Sushiswap'
        } else {
            reserves = await getReserves(uPair)
            exchangeToBuy = 'Sushiswap'
            exchangeToSell = 'Uniswap'
        }

        console.log(`Reserves on ${_routerPath[1]._address}`)
        console.log(`SHIB: ${Number(web3.utils.fromWei(reserves[0].toString(), 'ether')).toFixed(0)}`)
        console.log(`WETH: ${web3.utils.fromWei(reserves[1].toString(), 'ether')}\n`)

        try {

            // This returns the amount of WETH needed
            let result = await _routerPath[0].methods.getAmountsIn(reserves[0], [_token0.address, _token1.address]).call()

            const token0In = result[0] // WETH
            const token1In = result[1] // SHIB

            result = await _routerPath[1].methods.getAmountsOut(token1In, [_token1.address, _token0.address]).call()

            console.log(`Estimated amount of WETH needed to buy enough SHIB on ${exchangeToBuy}\t\t| ${web3.utils.fromWei(token0In, 'ether')}`)
            console.log(`Estimated amount of WETH returned after swapping SHIB on ${exchangeToSell}\t| ${web3.utils.fromWei(result[1], 'ether')}\n`)

            const { amountIn, amountOut } = await getEstimatedReturn(token0In, _routerPath, _token0, _token1)

            let ethBalanceBefore = await web3.eth.getBalance(account)
            ethBalanceBefore = web3.utils.fromWei(ethBalanceBefore, 'ether')
            const ethBalanceAfter = ethBalanceBefore - estimatedGasCost

            const amountDifference = amountOut - amountIn
            let wethBalanceBefore = await _token0Contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
            wethBalanceBefore = web3.utils.fromWei(wethBalanceBefore, 'ether')

            const wethBalanceAfter = amountDifference + Number(wethBalanceBefore)
            const wethBalanceDifference = wethBalanceAfter - Number(wethBalanceBefore)

            const totalGained = wethBalanceDifference - Number(estimatedGasCost)

            const data = {
                'ETH Balance Before': ethBalanceBefore,
                'ETH Balance After': ethBalanceAfter,
                'ETH Spent (gas)': estimatedGasCost,
                '-': {},
                'WETH Balance BEFORE': wethBalanceBefore,
                'WETH Balance AFTER': wethBalanceAfter,
                'WETH Gained/Lost': wethBalanceDifference,
                '-': {},
                'Total Gained/Lost': totalGained
            }

            console.table(data)
            console.log()

            if (amountOut < amountIn) {
                return false
            }

            amount = token0In
            return true

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            console.log(`\nError occured while trying to determine profitability...\n`)
            console.log(`This can typically happen because an issue with reserves, see README for more information.\n`)
            return false
        }
    }

    const executeTrade = async (_routerPath, _token0Contract, _token1Contract) => {
        console.log(`Attempting Arbitrage...\n`)

        let startOnUniswap

        if (_routerPath[0]._address == uRouter._address) {
            startOnUniswap = true
        } else {
            startOnUniswap = false
        }

        // Fetch token balance before
        const balanceBefore = await _token0Contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
        const ethBalanceBefore = await web3.eth.getBalance(account)

        if (config.PROJECT_SETTINGS.isDeployed) {
            await arbitrage.methods.executeTrade(startOnUniswap, _token0Contract._address, _token1Contract._address, amount).send({ from: account, gas: gas })
        }

        console.log(`Trade Complete:\n`)

        // Fetch token balance after
        const balanceAfter = await _token0Contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
        const ethBalanceAfter = await web3.eth.getBalance(account)

        const balanceDifference = balanceAfter - balanceBefore
        const totalSpent = ethBalanceBefore - ethBalanceAfter

        const data = {
            'ETH Balance Before': web3.utils.fromWei(ethBalanceBefore, 'ether'),
            'ETH Balance After': web3.utils.fromWei(ethBalanceAfter, 'ether'),
            'ETH Spent (gas)': web3.utils.fromWei((ethBalanceBefore - ethBalanceAfter).toString(), 'ether'),
            '-': {},
            'WETH Balance BEFORE': web3.utils.fromWei(balanceBefore.toString(), 'ether'),
            'WETH Balance AFTER': web3.utils.fromWei(balanceAfter.toString(), 'ether'),
            'WETH Gained/Lost': web3.utils.fromWei(balanceDifference.toString(), 'ether'),
            '-': {},
            'Total Gained/Lost': `${web3.utils.fromWei((balanceDifference - totalSpent).toString(), 'ether')} ETH`
        }

        console.table(data)
    }

    main()
    i++;


} while (i < arbAgainstLength);
```

The code itself appears to be running properly, except for the fact that certain wallet addresses like `0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca` throw an error.  The error is
`Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="toNumber", value="34961168813970327555695277297180835388765524858413590296049745231963419049984", code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)`

I believe I've traced this back to [this article](https://github.com/web3/web3.js/issues/3897) which describes the problem being that the contract for that address isn't ERC20 compliant, but I don't really understand how to fix it, especially across multiple addresses (multiple addresses are having this issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, indeed, due to the way the MKR contract is drafted.  Following the solution in the article I linked solves that problem.  For all other issues related to addresses, it's just a question of ensuring your address is checksummed (aka uses capitalization)